# How to develop newsletter using PHPmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I developed a newsletter system and I use `PHPmailer` class.

I have list of mails stored in database. It counts about 2000 e-mail addresses.

I want to send about 100-200 e-mails at once because I am sure I can not send all 2000 at once. Is there better way of cron job? Here is the code.

```
if($emailList = complexSelectQuery("SELECT email, hash FROM newsletter WHERE state='1'")){
    foreach($emailList as $email){
        $mail->msgHTML(createTemplate(1, $email['hash'], $message_id));
        $mail->AddBcc($email['email']);
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: It works fine with small list of e-mails.*

Comment: how this is hosted will determine if you can loop 2k or are limited, some hosts would limit you to X per hour. so you need to find out that first

Answer (score 0):

To send a great amount of messages you must care with your server daily sent limit.

You can schedule a cronjob to run your script and alter your SQL adding a limit clause

1. Select all messages with state = 1 and error = 0
2. If sent success alter message state to 0
3. If sent error alter error state to 1, optionally you can add a field to store the sent error message

Doing this, you will avoid your select to get messages that couldn't be send due to errors and will be able to track those errors and try to repair/re send those messages later